# reactive programming multiple action buttons same value rendering issue

Tags: r, shiny

I have 4 action buttons...but want same return value name. Since it is used in other elements. I initialize the reactive element as

```
myReactiveDF <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)

myReactiveDF <- eventReactive(input$action1, {
call functions
return(dataframe)
})

myReactiveDF <- eventReactive(input$action2, {
call functions
return(dataframe)
})
.....
```

However only the last button 4 works. The first three do not.
All the other elements use the same reactive element (`dataframe`) to get populated.
I tried `observeEvent` but it doesn't return values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should address your requirement as I understand them:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(2, selectInput('action1', label = "Action1:", choices =  c('a','b') )),
           column(4, selectInput('action2', label = "Action2:", choices =  c('A','B') ))),
  fluidRow( verbatimTextOutput("outputs"))
)

server = function(input, output, session){

  v <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$action1, {
    v$data <- input$action1
  })

  observeEvent(input$action2, {
    v$data <- input$action2
  })

  output$outputs <- renderText({ 
    if (is.null(v$data)) return()
    v$data
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If what you need is different, please let me know so that I can amend the answer.