# Multiple inputs to reactive value R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

For part of a Shiny application I am building, I need to have the user select a directory. The directory path is stored in a reactive variable. The directory can either be selected by the user from a file window or the path can be manually entered by `textInput`. I have figured out how to do this, but I don't understand why the solution I have works! A minimal example of the working app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(  
   actionButton("button1", "First Button"),
   textInput("inText", "Input Text"),
   actionButton("button2", "Second Button"),
   textOutput("outText"),
   textOutput("outFiles")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues(inDir = NULL)
  observeEvent(input$button1, {values$inDir <- tcltk::tk_choose.dir()})
  observeEvent(input$button2, {values$inDir <- input$inText})
  inPath <- eventReactive(values$inDir, {values$inDir})
  output$outText <- renderText(inPath())
  fileList <- reactive(list.files(path=inPath()))
  output$outFiles <- renderPrint(fileList())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The first thing I tried was to just use `eventReactive` and assign the two sources of input to the reactive variable:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
   inPath <- eventReactive(input$button1, {tcltk::tk_choose.dir()})
   inPath <- eventReactive(input$button2, {input$inText})
   output$outText <- renderText(inPath())  
   fileList <- reactive(list.files(path=inPath()))
   output$outFiles <- renderPrint(fileList()) 
}
```

The effect of this as far as I can tell is that only one of the buttons does anything. What I don't really understand is why this doesn't work. What I thought would happen is that the first button pushed would create `inPath` and then subsequent pushes would update the value and trigger updates to dependent values (here `output$outText`). What exactly is happening here then?

The second thing I tried, which was almost there, was based off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41564335/reactive-programming-multiple-action-buttons-same-value-rendering-issue):

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues(inDir = NULL)
  observeEvent(input$button1, {values$inDir <- tcltk::tk_choose.dir()})
  observeEvent(input$button2, {values$inDir <- input$inText})
  inPath <- reactive({if(is.null(values$inDir)) return()
                      values$inDir})
  output$outText <- renderText(inPath())
  fileList <- reactive(list.files(path=inPath()))
  output$outFiles <- renderPrint(fileList())
}
```

This works correctly except that it shows an "Error: invalid 'path' argument" message for `list.files`. I think this may mean that `fileList` is being evaluated with `inPath = NULL`. Why does this happen when I use `reactive` instead of `eventReactive`?

Thanks!

Comment: A few things aren't clear to me. (1) Why are you using `tcltk::` in a shiny app, why not browser-allowed file selectors? (2) Once the user identifies the path, what are you intending to do with it, just list the files within? (Is that all?)

Comment: @r2evans (1) The app is an interface for a report generator on a certain set of files that we analyze. The intent is that some of my coworkers who do not know how to use `r` can run them without having to ask me to do it. The files are hosted on a server, so none of the browser-allowed file selectors worked. (2) Once the user chooses the directory, the files are listed and then I use some regex to sort and display them. The user can then check what files they want to run the reports on, and the file paths are one of the inputs to a `knitr` file.

Comment: You're telling me that `tcltk::tk_choose.dir()` opens a directory-chooser *on the server* that the user can select? This Tk modal popup works through a browser interface?

Comment: @r2evans The directory chooser works as you would expect, what I meant was that when the app is run it is necessary to be able to choose files that are on the local network. It was the only chooser I could find that allowed the selection of network, not just local files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get rid of the `inPath` reactive and just use `values$inDir` instead.
With `req()` you'll wait until values are available. Otherwise you'll get the same error (*invalid 'path' argument*).

The `reactive` triggers right away, while the `eventReactive` will wait until the given event occurs and the eventReactive is called.

And `if(is.null(values$inDir)) return()` won't work correctly, as it will return NULL if `values$inDir` is NULL, which is then passed to `list.files`. And `list.files(NULL)` gives the error: `invalid 'path' argument`.

Replace it with `req(values$inDir)` and you won't get that error.

And your example with **2** `inPath` - eventReactive's won't work, as the first one will be overwritten by the second one, so `input$button1` won't trigger anything.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(  
  actionButton("button1", "First Button"),
  textInput("inText", "Input Text"),
  actionButton("button2", "Second Button"),
  textOutput("outText"),
  textOutput("outFiles")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues(inDir = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$button1, {values$inDir <- tcltk::tk_choose.dir()})
  observeEvent(input$button2, {values$inDir <- input$inText})
  output$outText <- renderText(values$inDir)

  fileList <- reactive({
    req(values$inDir); 
    list.files(path=values$inDir)
  })

  output$outFiles <- renderPrint(fileList())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

You could also use an `eventReactive` for `button1` and an `observeEvent` for `button2`, but note that you need an extra `observe({ inPath() })` to make it work. I prefer the above solution, as it is more clear what's happening and also less code.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues(inDir = NULL)

  inPath = eventReactive(input$button1, {values$inDir <- tcltk::tk_choose.dir()})
  observe({
    inPath()
  })

  observeEvent(input$button2, {values$inDir <- input$inText})
  output$outText <- renderText(values$inDir)

  fileList <- reactive({
    req(values$inDir); 
    list.files(path=values$inDir)
  })

  output$outFiles <- renderPrint(fileList())
}
```

---

And to illustrate why `if(is.null(values$inDir)) return()` won't work, consider the following function:

```
test <- function() { if (TRUE) return() }
test()
```

Although the **if**-condition evaluates to **TRUE**, there is still gonna be a return value (in this case **NULL**), which will be passed on to the following functions and in your case `list.files`, which will cause the error.